# Detect if the currently opened document is a post

Tags: posts

I am working on a plugin that, among many other things, adds some meta tags to the page.

It is important that those tags are added only when a post is opened, not some category or central page that perhaps contains links and excerpts from several posts, but as such is not focused on one particular post.

How can that be detected, and at what hook should this detection should be placed?

Comment: What exactly do you mean here? Do you want to check if `$current_post_id` is a post like `if (get_post_type($current_post_id) == 'post')` or via conditional tags like `is_singular()` etc? Or do you want to target a specific post by its ID?

Comment: Have you checked out all the existing template tags like `is_single()` and `is_singular()` and actions like `wp_head`?